# Why does Chrome crash at around 1.5 GB of memory usage?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, memory

In Chrome 21.0.1180.89 m, my tab crashes at about 1.5 GB of memory used.

Is this a limitation of v8? If so, can I increase the maximum memory used?

In Firefox it's working without problems up to 3 GB of RAM. I haven't tested more but that would fit my needs.

I use Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Is 1.5GB for all the tabs together or a single tab? The chrome binary for Windows from Google is still 32-bit, so you're still limited by the 3GB virtual address space limit. Because chrome creates a process for each tab, there may be large chunks of memory shared by the tabs that are not reflected in the process's private memory numbers. You may get a better idea if you check the virtual size of the processes as well.

Comment: it's a single tab, I'm doing some webgl stuff and load lots of data - I just downloaded canary build which is working fine.

Comment: *> Is this a limitation of v8?*   The JavaScript engine? `o.O`

Answer (score 3):

At the time this question was written, the following statements were true:

1) Chrome for Windows was not LargeAddressAware. This limited the maximum address space for a single Chrome process to 2gb.

2) Chrome for Windows used DirectX 9. This means a buffer in system memory had to be created to match the amount of video memory available. So on a 512mb videocard, Chrome would need to keep an additional 512mb buffer in memory.

Hence, the process would crash at 1.5gb 'used' memory: 1.5gb for the process, and an additional 512mb for the GPU.

Comment: SU decided to show me this question in Related. I'd already written the answer before noting the date, and didn't want to waste the typing.

Answer (score 1):

As long as there is still plenty of memory available on your system (>1GB), then the crash should not be attributed to memory. The more likely reason is one of Chrome's installed extension or complicated rendering causing the crash. Your comment on

> webgl stuff and load lots of data

could be the clue. You can look at previous crashes by typing this in the `Omnibox` :

chrome://crashes/

You can then submit the crash reports to the Chromium team.

Should you wish to troubleshoot the crash yourself, follow the [instructions here](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/reporting-crash-bug). Basically  you need to:

- Look for Chrome crash in Windows Event Viewer `eventvwr.exe` to identify the crash ID, and get the crash dump file from `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\CrashReports\Chrome-last.dmp`
- Get the crash details from `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State`

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**
Update to Chrome 64 bits.

**Long answer:**

At the time of this writing, I was facing this same problem on a Windows 10 64 bits, while trying to open a huge spreadsheet on Google Docs.

The fact was that my computer had the most updated version of the 32 bits of Google Chrome.

The others answers on this post gave me insight on MANUALLY update to the 64 bits version, and it solved the issue.

Chrome 32 bits is limited to addressing around 1.5GB of RAM per tab.